# Why does libtcod.console_put_char keep returning "ctypes.ArgumentError"

Tags: python, ctypes, libtcod

**The Code so far:
http://pastie.org/private/wcjqodm9pm66aorks9jp7w**

When running the code, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Tyler/Documents/Third Party Games/Python/RogueLike/RogueLike.py", line 224, in <module>
render_all()
File "C:/Users/Tyler/Documents/Third Party Games/Python/RogueLike/RogueLike.py", line 173, in render_all
object.draw()
File "C:/Users/Tyler/Documents/Third Party Games/Python/RogueLike/RogueLike.py", line 69, in draw
libtcod.console_put_char(con, self.x, self.y, self.char, libtcod.BKGND_NONE)
File "C:\Users\Tyler\Documents\Third Party Games\Python\RogueLike\libtcodpy.py", line 765, in console_put_char
_lib.TCOD_console_put_char(con, x, y, ord(c), flag)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 2
```

The issue seems to be line 69:

```
libtcod.console_put_char(con, self.x, self.y, self.char, libtcod.BKGND_NONE)
```

It doesnt like self.x or self.y

I've had a similar problem on line 213:

```
player = Object(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "@", libtcod.white)
```

But I managed to dodgily fix it by replacing SCREEN_WIDTH and SCREEN_HEIGHT with their actual values, rather than the variable names.

Doesn't seem I can fix my current problem this way however.

Comment: Be mindful of operations that return floating point values. In Python 3 the division operator `/` is true division (`__truediv__`), not classic division (`__div__`). So `SCREEN_WIDTH / 2` is a `float`. Similarly in the `center` method the expression `(self.x1 + self.x2) / 2` is a floating point value. Python 2.2 introduced the floor division (`__floordiv__`) operator `//`. Use this operator to implement integer division, e.g. `SCREEN_WIDTH // 2`.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks so much, that fixed it perfectly